# Is it Possible To Create an Upload File Script Without PHP (And have it accepted by the server)

Tags: javascript, html

The Question is pretty self explanatory, I looked around and I could not find much information on the subject, but is it possible to create a fully functioning upload file script without using php and have it be accepted by the server? Preferably looking for something using HTML/Jscript. If you have also seen anywhere where a script like this exists, I'd appreciate the redirection. Thank you.

Comment: Sure it is but then it all depends on what *else* you have working on server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload a file using purely Javascript, but you need PHP or some other server side solution on the server in order to accept the download and save it to the server.

What problem are you trying to fix exactly? Whatever it is, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: It is more just curiosity, I was wondering what I could use instead of PHP so that the server could accept the download/save it. Thanks again.

Comment: You could use NodeJS (server-side Javascript), Rails (uses Ruby), Django (uses Python), or many others.

Comment: Here's the concept:  Javascript = scripts that is being run on your computer/mobile.  You still need a server side to work with your javascript since it is only way if you want your file to be on the server.  Generally speaking, PHP usually is used for that purpose.  However, you should look into skimberk1's suggestion since that's growing into a popular technique.